# EGit + Beanstalk - Auth Fail

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, egit

I have Eclipse 3.5 and EGit 0.9.3 installed. Gitbash can authenticate fine to Beanstalk, but for some reason Eclipse gives me Auth Failed when I try to import/clone a repo into Eclipse.

Also, I don't seem to have git+ssh as a protocol option - why is that? I have copied my files from .ssh to ssh as some other posts have indicated but it still does not work.

I have tried adding git+ssh:// to the URI. I also tried SSH protocol. When I select git protocol, I get an error saying "User not supported on git protocol."

How can I use EGit to work with Beanstalk repositories?

Comment: same thing, also I've tried to update eclipse to helios sr1 - still no luck, please help. What i've tried - from GIT command line (msysgit) ssh git@myname.beanstalk.com - everything fine - it asked a password and it's ok. In eclipse I tried: user: git, protocol: ssh, everything else as in clone. Then eclipse asked me for password for user git, I've entered and nothing. By the way, maybe someone knows where eclipse ssh stores it's logs, it might be helpful.

Comment: I've tried to put keys into ssh directory. From the other point, it's possible to configure where keys will be stored (Prefs -> Network -> SSH2), by default it searches in ssh directory, but it's possible to set any other directory. The problem arise is when I'm trying to clone and EGit asks for password for user git for key in ssh directory. When I put my git password, it says auth fail. The worst thing - I can't even find the log of the EGit or the connection to find out where is the problem. P.S. command line connection works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, same problem I had. Try deleting your keys and restarting, authenticate in the console before opening Eclipse. Copy files from .ssh to ssh, then attempt a clone. When I did that, I was finally able to do it in Eclipse. Eclipse should then ask for your keypass, leave git protocol and authentication fields blank.

Comment: are you sure about git protocol? I thought that protocol should be ssh and in authentication fields username must be 'git'.

Comment: could you please give a screenshot for your beanstalk EGit repository connection screen?

Comment: I never touched the protocol or auth fields. When you click COPY on the repo link in beanstalk then click Clone in Eclipse, the only thing you then have to do is click Next.

Comment: @Thank you very much. Regenerating keys really helped. And I think I know what the problem was. It's only an assumption, but at first I've copied my public key to my beanstalk profile without ending linebreak, it seems that for command line git it's not critical, but it is that for eclipse. In the second try, I've copied all public key to my profile, including line break and now everything works in eclipse too.